# Why is this jquery code not working as I expect?

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name" /><input type="button" id="insert" value="Insert" />
<div id="display_list"></div>
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function display() {
        $('#display_list').text('');
        $.each(names, function(index, value) {
            $('#display_list').append(index + 1 + '. ' + value + '<br/>');
        });
    }
    var names = ['cow', 'alex', 'ram'];
    display();
    $('#insert').click(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        names.push(name);
        display();
    });
});
```

The problem is it is showing

1. cow
2. alex
3. ram

at first , but when I type something at input and click insert box, it is not showing any value but incremented index numbers, something like this:

1. cow
2. alex
3. ram
4.   5.

Comment: what is '#name' ? Is it a input type text? What happens if you console.log $('#name').val(), on click, do you get the correct value?

Comment: can you show us what you are trying using jsfiddle

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/jVWWc/

Comment: $('#name') is the id selector of an input field ,like <input type"text" id="name" />

Comment: @Rumplin why? granted it can be useful, but the problem is many people use jsfiddle then don't bother posting their code here.  Posting it here is a much better option, if a jsfiddle is needed later then one can be created.

Comment: @babu as Felix pointed out, the code does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.trim()` to check that input value is not empty:

```
 $('#insert').click(function(){
   var name= $.trim($('#name').val())
   if (name != "") {  
      names.push(name);
      display();
  } 
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ntu79/)

Comment: ok using  jsfiddle.net/fkling/jVWWc it is working fine , but why it is not working on the webpage ? i mean just indexs are comming and not values.

Comment: i tried your code and it's working fine as expected. Try to alert the value in your iteration as well as the value you push in your array to trace it.

Comment: @babu Sorry I cannot see your webpage.

Comment: never mind , thanks everyone , some other function was conflicting with this one , that is why it was not working